# In the Minimalist Program, can valued uninterpretable features still act as goals before they are deleted?

Tags: syntax, grammar

the title pretty much says it, if deletion happens with shipping to the interfaces SEM/PHON, can a valued, uninterpretable feature still be a goal for another probe of this feature? In a DP, maybe as long as the whole DP is not deactivated by Case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depends on the software the Program is written in, and which libraries your version is using.

Comment: Multiple Agree (or multiple feature checking)?

Comment: @jlawler don't troll new users

Comment: @curiousdannii: Sorry; my previous comment should be understood metaphorically, not literally. I'm just waiting for a official minimalist answer.

Comment: Me too, I'd like to see an official "minimalist" answer. The question is narrow, quite specific to a particular paradigm. Let's see if anyone can produce an answer that a more general audience might understand.